# Drag bound not working for a resized image in kineticjs

Tags: image-processing, canvas, kineticjs, drag, image-resizing

I am using Kineticjs. I am trying to have bound (dragBoundFunc) on  the drag like the one below (http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/n5xMs):

```
        dragBoundFunc: function (pos) {
            var X = pos.x;
            var Y = pos.y;
            if (X < minX) {
                X = minX;
            }
            if (X > maxX) {
                X = maxX;
            }
            if (Y < minY) {
                Y = minY;
            }
            if (Y > maxY) {
                Y = maxY;
            }
            return ({
                x: X,
                y: Y
            });
        }
    });
```

and I am trying use this approach for a group which is drag-able and re-sizable like this http://jsbin.com/iyimuy/125/edit but I am not able to make it work.I would love to hear some comments.

Comment: I have spent most of my day on this but can't seem to make it work.Please reply by improving/editting the jsBin file

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be overthinking the problem.

For example, here’s how to enforce the right boundary (in pseudo-code).

You have moved darth beyond the right side of yoda if:

```
darthRight > yodaRight.
```

**Calculate darthRight:**

In dragBoundFunc, the pos variable gives you the current top-left x/y of darth.

```
darthRight = posX + darthWidth
```

**Calculate yodaRight:**

```
yodaRight = yodaX + yodaWidth
```

**To correct for darths move outside yoda:**

Pull darths left side back inside yoda until its a full darthWidth inside yodaRight.

```
posX = yodaRight - darthWidth
```

Done!

Now repeat for the other 3 boundaries...

Comment: @makE I know the conditions which need to be enforced but I was not able to make it work correctly as you may have seen I have tried to solve the problem by similar approach (note  yodaX=0), only difference is that I tried to increase bound by 10 as I wanted the anhors to be inside the yoda image all the time.Moreover, I am not sure how to implement the condition when both x and y are out of bounds.Could you please do the appropriate changes to the jsbin file.It would of great help to me.

Comment: I also forgot to mention the i am not sure how to handle the bound problem which arises when we resize the darthvader image

Comment: I was able to improve the code but there are still some problems which i am not able to figure out.. check out this updated code http://jsbin.com/iyimuy/132/edit

Comment: http://jsbin.com/iyimuy/133/edit, I am still not able to mange the bound after the re-size.Please help

Comment: Good work! I tried your jsbin and it looks like you have it working now.  The one thing I would add is that when resizing you should prevent the user from drag-resizing beyond the border of yoda.

Comment: if you resize the image, then the bounds are messed up.Could you please fix that error.